# What is the attribute data-mouseover for?

Tags: javascript, html

On a webpage, I found several images with the following structure:

```
<img src="/image.png"
     class="images"
     data-mouseover="/mouse_over_image.png">
```

When putting the mouse over them, I found out that the image **src** changes to their **data-mouseover** value, and they change back when the mouse is not over anymore.

I didn't find anything by searching 'data-mouseover' neither here nor on Google. Where does this attribute belong to? (some sort of framework, maybe?), and how is it used to achieve this effect?

Comment: This is being done by a plugin that you've loaded.

Comment: If you post the URL of the web page, we can probably tell you which plugin is doing it.

Comment: @Barmar actually, the 'webpage' I mentioned did not use anything besides jQuery to achieve this. I does something similar to the [answer I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37055087/4257747). Instead of putting a link to the webpage, I could edit the question and add the webpage's code itself, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching on the MDN I found info about the [data-* global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) .

There it says that **data-*** attributes of an html element are a class of global attributes called 'custom attributes'. They allow information to be exchanged between the HTML and its DOM representation, which can/may be used in scripts.

The way the effect of changing the image on mouseover works is actually quite simple, and can be implemented by adding 'mouseover' 'mouseout' event listeners. Here is a simple script using jQuery and editing **data-*** attributes to achieve this effect.

```js
$(".img_change").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).data("mouseout", this.src);
  this.src = $(this).data("mouseover");

});
$(".img_change").mouseout(function() {
  this.src = $(this).data("mouseout");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/e7dnas.png" class="img_change" data-mouseover="http://i66.tinypic.com/2j5x6l1.png">
```